# Running a webserver in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

If I wanted to have a webserver run in flutter, during development when I reload it will reload the server.  If I have something like:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    try {
      startWebServer();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Couldn't bind to port 8000: $e");
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

every time I reload the app it starts a new webserver.  I realize I could pass `shared: True` to `bind`, but this seems like it will create a ton of webservers when I really only want one.  Should I make webserver global or is there a way to only start the webserver on startup, and close on shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about declaring a webserver variable outside the scope of the build. Maybe even outside the scope of the class. The instance then may persist across a hot reload.

```
MyWebServ myWs;  // option 1
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static MyWebServ myWs;   // option 2
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    try {
      if (myWs == null)
        myWs = startWebServer();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Couldn't bind to port 8000: $e");
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it to Stateful Widget

use initState() to start the webserver when you open the widget

```
@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 startWebServer();
}
```

when you close the widget you want to stop the webserver use dispose()

```
@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _stopWebServer();
}
```

check [Stateful Widget Lifecycle](https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/)